# Añadir una columna según varias condiciones en varias columnas (pandas)

Tags: python, string, pandas

Tengo esta base de datos con 23 columnas y 1882 entradas.ejemplo:

| Titulo | Resumen | Año | key words |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Ciencias sociales y eduación | "tal, tal..." | 2014 | education; social |

Actualmente hago este filtro a la base de datos según esta condición:

```
f = ['sociology', 'Sociology', 'SOCIOLOGY', 'SOCIOLOGICAL', 'sociological']


bd[bd[['Titulo','Resumen', 'Author Keywords',
       'Revista Keywords']].apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(f),case=False).any(), axis=1)]
```

A las filas que saca me gustaría poder añadir una nueva columna que ponga ponga "sociologia"
ejemplo:

| Titulo | Resumen | Año | key words | Clasificacion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Ciencias sociales y eduación | "tal, tal..." | 2014 | education; social | sociología |

No sé de que manera podría continuar el código. Gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir un enlace al dataframe completo (o al menos a unas cuantas filas de ejemplo) para poder hacer pruebas sobre datos reales? Si no no se pueden hacer pruebas y es muy difícil responder con algo que vaya a funcionar bien.

Comment: si pero no sé como puedo adjuntar los datos?

Comment: Lo más sencillo es que lo subas a algún disco en la nube (dropbox, drive, onedrive...) y compartas el enlace. Otra opción puede ser copiarlo como texto y pegarlo en la pregunta, encerrado entre una línea con tres ``` al inicio y otra al final, para que salga formateado como código. En este segundo caso no metas el dataframe completo, sino solo un extracto.

Answer (score 0):

Primero crea la columna con un valor default

```
db['Clasificacion'] = 'Desconocido'
```

Despues crea el filtro y modifica la columna que quieres.

```
filtro = bd[['Titulo','Resumen', 'Author Keywords',
       'Revista Keywords']].apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(f),case=False).any(), axis=1)

db.loc[filtro, 'Clasificacion'] = 'sociología'
```